# SASS watcher to watch all folders, compile to one CSS

Tags: css, npm, sass, watch

I'd like to watch this kind of folder structure:

```
assets
- scss
  - folder
      file.scss
      anotherfile.scss
      anotherfile.scss
      anotherfile.scss
  - anotherfolder
      file.scss
      anotherfile.scss
      anotherfile.scss
      anotherfile.scss
- css
    main.css
```

.. to 1 main.css. I use npm run scss + node-sass, read from a package.json file:

```
{
 "name": "test",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": " ",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "scss": "node-sass --watch assets/sass/app.scss assets/css/app.css"
 },
 "license": "ISC",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
   "npm-sass": "^2.2.1"
 }
}
```

When I change things in subfolders, it IS written to main.css, but also to a CSS file like css>folder>anotherfile.css. And it is giving errors because when I change scss>folder>anotherfile.scss the compiler cannot find variables, because it seems unaware of the vars.scss file I've loaded in my main.scss.

I don't want that. How can you watch an entire folder structure, but only compile main.scss to main.css when something changes? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Watch a few tutorials on youtube. Like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTBaQ2DcGUk

Answer (score 2):

Rename all files except `main.scss` to have underscore before name e.g. `anotherfile.scss` => `_anotherfile.scss`